# restarting documetum server repository not show in drop down list in login page

Tags: documentum

I have just install the developer edition of documentum it was working successfully on window 7. but whenever I restart my system then login page don’t have any repository in drop down list. kindly help me

Comment: Login to which app, exactly?

Comment: it is because there is no docbroker listed on your dfc.properties. 
Please show me dfc.properties inside your documentum/config folder

Comment: I have restart my system 2 -3 times it working successfully . Issue was that application not starting in a flow (means that first start docbase then start docbroker etc.) Still I can't understand my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Startup sequence is very important for Documentum.
Correct startup Sequence is

- Documentum DocBroker Service
- Documentum Docbase Service "Repository Name"
- Documentum Java Method Server
- your application (for example Apache Tomcat with Webtop or Taskspace)

Usually on Windows it is Windows Services. When you just restart your server windows can start it in different order. To automate this procedure it is possible to configure Windows Service Dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times when this problem occurs, repository didn't start yet, and docbroker doesn't have information about it (repository didn't informed docbroker about its availlability).

If you look in the repository log (located under *%DOCUMENTUM%\dba\log*) you will see at the end of the startup process line like

```
Thu Jul 31 15:55:33 2014 301000 [DM_DOCBROKER_I_PROJECTING]info:  "Sending information to 
Docbroker located on host (TESTSERVER) with port (1489).  Information: (Config(documentum), 
Proximity(1), Status(Open))."
```

At this point docbroker knows about this repository and your client applications will have it in the list of available repositories.